# Why positronium can annihilate in vacuum?

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, momentum, neutrinos, positronium

I thought that the annihilation process of positronium cannot take place without a third-party particle. This can be directly derived from energy & momentum conservation:

energy conservation: $$h\omega=E_e+E_p+E_{third}$$
momentum conservation: $$\frac{h\omega}{c}\hat{\vec{n}}=\frac{\vec{V}_e E_e}{c^2}+\frac{\vec{V}_p E_p}{c^2}+\frac{\vec{V}_{third} E_{third}}{c^2}$$

Short transformation of these two formulas lead to:
$$|\frac{\vec{V}_e E_e}{c}+\frac{\vec{V}_p E_p}{c}+\frac{\vec{V}_{third} E_{third}}{c}|=E_e+E_p+E_{third}$$

Where $h\omega$ is a sum over all created photons, $\hat{\vec{n}}$ is a unit vector.

If there is no third particle, then this process cannot happen, because it would mean that electron and positron velocities had to be equal to speed of light. We cannot use vacuum fluctuations here, because vacumm balance must be preserved too (zero energy and zero momentum overall in vacuum fluctuations).

I start to wonder if that can become possible if only higher decay modes are used: three or five photons in case of parallel spin of $e^{+}$ and $e^{-}$, four or six photons in case of antiparallel spin. But it seems impossible for me, because the $E_{third}$ term has to be massive otherwise would just cancel out from both sides  (because if the created particle is an extra photon it has a speed of light, and $E_{third}$ terms are equal). It seems to me that some massive particle must be created or participate along the way. Maybe for example a neutrino and antineutrino (created) or just some neutrino (participate)? Maybe this is another example showing that neutrinos have mass?

EDIT: well it appears that with your help we have found an answer. My original question ignored vectors. Now that the third formula includes a vector magnitude of momentum times c, the third particle can be a photon, and they cannot cancel out.

Comment: This iwhy you need at least 2 photons - your $E_{\rm third}$ can be another photon.

Comment: momentum is a vector and the second formula ignores the masses of the e an p too.

Comment: mass of electron and proton is $E/c^2$, the vector part is within velocity.

Comment: $E_{third}$ cannot be another photon, because then $V_{third}=c$ and it just cancels out.

Comment: oh, you are right. $E_{third}$ can be a photon, because after I fixed the question using vectors properly it no longer can cancel out.

Comment: of course I meant positron, not proton.

Comment: It is pair production by Xrays that needs an interaction with a field in order to conserve momentum in the cms. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/releng.html#c4

Comment: I think the confusion comes from your hW  .  E/c for a complex system of particles is not hW/c .

Comment: @annav What exactly do you mean by confusion? I wrote that $E=h\omega$ is a sum of all emitted photons, and their momentum would be summed like that: $\frac{h\omega}{c}\hat{\vec{n}}_{resultant}=\sum_{i=0}^N{\frac{h\omega_i}{c} {\hat{\vec{n}}}_i}$ Why this is incorrect?

Comment: Alternatively if that is correct, then maybe I should add it to the question, to make it more clear. Oh, wait.... a sum of unit vectors will not produce a unit vector. It has to be normalized afterwards, but I cannot edit that comment anymore.

Comment: also a sum of frequencies will not be  a frequency. a sum of photons has invariant mass .

Comment: So in fact the momentum would be, I suppose: $\frac{h\omega}{c}\hat{\vec{n}}_{resultant}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^N\frac{h\omega_i}{c}{\hat{\vec{n}}}_{i}} {|{\sum_{i=0}^N\frac{h\omega_i}{c}{\hat{\vec{n}}}_{i}}|}$ That is quite a mess. If this is not correct, then what is the correct approach? To remind why I think it could be like this: I treat this as a sum of photon momentum vectors, not energies.

Comment: Oops, I didn't get it right. In above comment it is just a unitary dimensionless vector $\hat{\vec{n}}_{resultant}$ (delete the $h\omega/c$ part). If we separate creation of normalized unit vector from the magnitude the denominator would cancel out. I conclude that the previous formula is the correct formula. It only doesn't tell how to find $\hat{\vec{n}}_{resultant}$(the above comment tells that). So I would stick with this formula: $\frac{h\omega}{c}\hat{\vec{n}}_{resultant}=\sum_{i=0}^N{\frac{h{\omega}_i}{c}{\hat{\vec{n}}_{i}}}$ Please tell me if that is correct approach:summing momentums.

Comment: If summing those momentum vectors is correct then i will edit my question by putting there formula from my above comment, so that it will be clear for everyone. And I am sorry for posting that many comments, I hope thet you forgive me.

Comment: Please don't put block equations in comments.

Answer (score 4):

The question is based on a misunderstanding.

We will do the work in  the center of mass frame of the incident particles, and assume a two photon final-state (in practice it also occurs to a thre-photon state). We have a total incident a four-vector of $(\gamma m_e c^2,\vec{0})$ (this simple form is why I chose to work in the CoM frame). The two photons leave back-to-back in this frame (necessary to conserve three-momentum) and each having energy $\frac{1}{2} m_e \gamma c^2$. Without loss of of generality we pick a coordinate system such that each has momentum lying along the z-axis, giving total momentum $\frac{1}{2} m_e \gamma c - \frac{1}{2} m_e \gamma c = 0$.

Four-momentum is conserved.

It would be incorrect at this point to say that the problem is solved, because there never *was* a problem.

Boosting to other frames is trivial and is left as an exercise.